# generate lines with all unique values of given column for each group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timePoint': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                        'item': [1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,1,3,7,2],
                       'value': [2,4,7,6,5,9,3,2,4,3,1,5]})

>>> df
    item  timePoint  value
0      1          1      2
1      2          1      4
2      3          1      7
3      4          1      6
4      3          2      5
5      4          2      9
6      5          2      3
7      6          2      2
8      1          3      4
9      3          3      3
10     7          3      1
11     2          3      5
```

In this `df`, not every `item` appears at every `timePoint`. I want to have all unique `items` at every `timePoint`, and these newly inserted `items` should either have:

(i) a `NaN` `value` if they have not appeared at a previous `timePoint`, or
(ii) if they have, they get their most recent `value`.

The desired output should look like the following (lines with hashtag are those inserted).

```
>>> dfx
    item  timePoint  value
0      1          1    2.0
3      1          2    2.0 #
8      1          3    4.0
1      2          1    4.0
4      2          2    4.0 #
11     2          3    5.0
2      3          1    7.0
4      3          2    5.0
9      3          3    3.0
3      4          1    6.0
5      4          2    9.0
6      4          3    9.0 #
0      5          1    NaN #
6      5          2    3.0 
7      5          3    3.0 #
1      6          1    NaN #
7      6          2    2.0 
8      6          3    2.0 #
2      7          1    NaN #
5      7          2    NaN #
10     7          3    1.0
```

For example, `item` `1` gets a `4.0` at `timePoint` `2` because that's what it had a `timePoint` `1` whereas `item` `6` gets a `NaN` at `timePoint` `1` because there is no preceding `value`.

Now, I know that if I manage to insert all lines of every unique `item` missing in each `timePoint` `group`, i.e. reach this point:

```
>>> dfx
    item  timePoint  value
0      1          1    2.0
1      2          1    4.0
2      3          1    7.0
3      4          1    6.0
4      3          2    5.0
5      4          2    9.0
6      5          2    3.0
7      6          2    2.0
8      1          3    4.0
9      3          3    3.0
10     7          3    1.0
11     2          3    5.0
0      5          1    NaN
1      6          1    NaN
2      7          1    NaN
3      1          2    NaN
4      2          2    NaN
5      7          2    NaN
6      4          3    NaN
7      5          3    NaN
8      6          3    NaN
```

Then I can do:

```
dfx.sort_values(by = ['item', 'timePoint'],
                                inplace = True,
                                ascending = [True, True])
dfx['value'] = dfx.groupby('item')['value'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

which will return the desired output.

But how do I add as lines all `df.item.unique()` `items` that are missing to each `timePoint` `group`?

Also, if you have a more efficient solution from scratch to suggest, then by all means please be my guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`, `levels`, `reindex`

```
d = df.set_index(['item', 'timePoint'])
d.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(d.index.levels, names=d.index.names)
).groupby(level='item').ffill().reset_index()

    item  timePoint  value
0      1          1    2.0
1      1          2    2.0
2      1          3    4.0
3      2          1    4.0
4      2          2    4.0
5      2          3    5.0
6      3          1    7.0
7      3          2    5.0
8      3          3    3.0
9      4          1    6.0
10     4          2    9.0
11     4          3    9.0
12     5          1    NaN
13     5          2    3.0
14     5          3    3.0
15     6          1    NaN
16     6          2    2.0
17     6          3    2.0
18     7          1    NaN
19     7          2    NaN
20     7          3    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In `pandas` `'0.19.2'`, when running the second line, I am getting `KeyError: 'item'`

Comment: you need `groupby(level='item')` then

Comment: Thanks. I'll change to accept this answer then because it also works as is with more than one value columns. Could you please update your answer with `groupby(level='item')` so it that works for everybody. Is this an issue related to `pandas` version or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is a version issue.  Newer versions allow to reference index level names.

Answer (score 2):

I think `stack` with `unstack` will achieve the format , then we using `groupby` `ffill`to fill the nan value forward

```
s=df.set_index(['item','timePoint']).value.unstack().stack(dropna=False)
s.groupby(level=0).ffill().reset_index()
Out[508]: 
    item  timePoint    0
0      1          1  2.0
1      1          2  2.0
2      1          3  4.0
3      2          1  4.0
4      2          2  4.0
5      2          3  5.0
6      3          1  7.0
7      3          2  5.0
8      3          3  3.0
9      4          1  6.0
10     4          2  9.0
11     4          3  9.0
12     5          1  NaN
13     5          2  3.0
14     5          3  3.0
15     6          1  NaN
16     6          2  2.0
17     6          3  2.0
18     7          1  NaN
19     7          2  NaN
20     7          3  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Extra question please. If I had more than one `value` cols in the original `df`, (e.g. `value1`, `value2` ..), would there be any way of following this approach, or would I have to repeat the process for each `value` column and then merge the resulting `df`s?

Comment: @Tony you can check Pir's answer